# Synology UPnP configuration

Tags: port-forwarding, nas, synology, upnp

I am trying to set up a home network using a **TP-Link Archer AX55** router to bridge the provider modem **Comtrend GRG-4280us**.

I have a **Synology NAS DS1019+** at home and I am attempting to configure it on the newly created network via Ethernet.

As I am a newbie at these tasks, I am encountering a lot of problems. One of them is really bothering me. It concerns UPnP port forwarding. It appears that my new router can only handle a maximum of 64 UPnP clients, or maybe it is the Synology, I am not sure. What I do know is that in the old network, I could configure as many clients as I wished, but not in the new one.

I inherited the old configuration, where I configured over a thousand ports. Now, I want to remove that configuration from my Synology, but I only receive the message "UPnP Service is busy. Please try again later." I want to eliminate one of the configurations to clear up this mess, but I have no idea how to proceed.

Do you have any advice on how to delete all the UPnP rules?

[image]

Comment: Does anything *need* UPnP? If not, [UPNP service is busy, try again later](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/131769) suggests disabling UPnP on the router and waiting for the NAS to settle down.